# SharePoint 2007 from scratch

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I've got to get up to speed on [Microsoft SharePoint 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/Sharepoint/default.mspx) over the next few months. I need to start from the beginning, so I need to know what it is and how to use it to build sites. Then I need to know how to develop using C# with it (web-parts and such).

Can anyone recommend a good series of articles or books that cover the creation, administration and development aspects of MOSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to any books or resources, you can grab free VHD's of a full MOSS 2007 server to play with, directly from Microsoft.  These come with 30 day self-destruct though so be warned.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en

Edit: I've found this to be useful to suggest to people who didn't realize MOSS isn't free like ASP.NET or WSS.  Your case may vary, but this is pretty darn useful for experimentation.

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the resources that you are searching for.. Hope they would be useful.

[Sharepoint eBooks](http://www.flazx.com/category202.php)